# Ecto keep saying "Unknown database"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to use ecto.migrate in order to install tables on my mysql session.

However even if ecto.create has succedded, Ecto.migrate fails with this error message :

```
15:53:20.563 [error] GenServer #PID<0.319.0> terminating
** (stop) %Mariaex.Error{mariadb: %{code: 1049, message: "Unknown database 'msg_gtw_dev'"}, message: nil}
Last message: nil
State: [sock_mod: Mariaex.Connection.Tcp, timeout: 5000, otp_app: :msg_gtw, repo: MsgGtw.Repo, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.MySQL, username: "root", password: "root", database: "msg_gtw_dev", hostname: "localhost", port: 3306]
```

after checking out the mysql, the database exist :

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| msg_gtw_dev        |
| mysql              |
| objectstore_dev    |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

I'm currently using a mac OS X el capitan, while this exact project works fine on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
iex -> 1.2.6
erl -> R18
ecto -> 1.1.9
```

EDIT : (asked by neydroid)
Here's the configuration :

```
# Configure your database      
config :msg_gtw, MsgGtw.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.MySQL,
  username: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "msg_gtw_dev",
  hostname: "127.0.0.1",
  pool_size: 10
```

Any idea ? solution ? work around ? tips & tricks ? ;-)

Comment: could you add the adapter config to the question?

Comment: sure thing ! @neydroid, done !

Comment: sorry for the question, are you starting the mariaex application inside mix.exs like `applications: [:phoenix, :cowboy, :logger,
  :phoenix_ecto, :mariaex]` ?

Comment: @neydroid, you should never apologize for helping ;-) And the answer is yes, like it is by default, I haven't touched a thing...

Comment: thanks! is pretty weird, it appears to be a connection problem https://github.com/xerions/mariaex/blob/aa73a4218db4f23ce16444b064dbe3ab1b9ac540/test/start_test.exs#L6 but there's the thing that you could run ecto.create

Comment: Can you access the MySQL with `mysql -u root -proot -h 127.0.0.1 -D msg_gtw_dev`?  The error message says hostname: "localhost", but in your config file, you specified "127.0.0.1". it's queer.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Yes the MySQL command works fine it is what I used to print the show databases command on my post.

Comment: Yes because I tried also 127.0.0.1 with no luck and copy pasted that. Sorry for the confusion